# Plotting a GAM contour plot with the response scale in tidymv

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I have created a GAM using the `mgcv` package with the gamma family. I then plot it with `tidymv` so that I use `ggplot2`. However, it plots the transformed values for the scale. How do I plot it in the response scale (0-1 in this case)?

Edited to add sample data and specified `k=2` in the example code so it will still run on the sample data.

```
sourceLambda = c(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2)
traitLambda = c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
meanT = c(1.052590e-04, 1.588049e-04, 9.678802e-05, 1.090665e-04, 1.265542e-04, 8.495936e-05, 1.399897e-04, 2.928686e-04, 2.481759e-04)
sdata = data.frame(sourceLambda, traitLambda, meanT)

library(tidymv)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis)

x= gam(meanT ~ s(sourceLambda, k=2)+s(traitLambda,k=2), data=cats1,Gamma)
x2 <- predict_gam(x)

x2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(sourceLambda, traitLambda, z = fit)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = fit)) +
  geom_contour(colour = "white") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_viridis("T1", option = "A")
```

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ZYp.png)

Comment: You can transform from the link scale to the observed scale by doing the inverse transformation.`Gamma()$linkinv()` is the function to do that, which for Gamma is just the inverse i.e. `1 / x`. So I think you want `z = 1 / fit` ? (I'm not sure, since I can't reproduce your code to have a look.)

Comment: Oh gotcha. I talked myself out of that because reading the `mgcv` documentation made me think there was some additional complexity. I forgot to add sample data so I've added that for posterity (and also added the` k=2` to the formula so it would still run)